# Robot framework installation

Tags: java, python, robotframework

I want to learn robot framework with java and python, but not sure how to use this?. I searched over the net but did not get steps to instal robot framework.

I installed only selenium2library file in my system, but not sure what to do next?.

Please share the steps or sample code or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on what you set up, in my environment I had Python, Java, PiP and EasyInstall loaded then it was simply a matter of running:

```
pip install robotframework
```

But it's simple enough to find the instructions on the [Robot Framework site](http://robotframework.org/) and check out the link to the [Installation Instructions](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation).

The Robot Framework site has links to examples as well, which should get you on your way as well.

Answer (score 3):

At least in [Robot Framework User Guide, Getting started](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#getting-started)
it has a nicely detailed installation instructions.

Comment: Jan and MichaelF: Above Links are very useful (Voted Up for this). And if I face any difficulties/need any suggestions in these I will get back to you people :).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below procedure to install robot framework on your system.

1. Install Python  on your machine(python2.6 - min version)
2. Install  wxPython(wxPython 2.8.12.1 )
3. Install Robot framework.
   If RIDE is used only to edit test cases, Robot Framework does not need to installed at all. However, the Test runner plugin requires Robot Framework to be separately installed
4. Install RIDE
5. Install Selenium2Library.
   `C:\Python27\Scripts> easy_install robotframework-selenium2library`.
   This will automatically install some packages(ex: docuitls,decorator) which are required to get Selenium2Library working on your system.
6. After a successful installation RIDE can be started from the command line by running ride.py as `C:\Python27\Scripts> ride.py`

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to install wxPython and RIDE -- you can use robot framework with plenty of other text editors.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch this [YouTube Playlist](https://youtu.be/8h5knh2jLCA) by Raghav Pal to install as well as learn Robot Framework. It is great for someone want to learn Robot Framework from scratch.